# Using SQL, how could I take a rolling average over a given number of days across an unspecified number of records each of those days?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, average, window-functions

I have the following fields. Each record below is unique.

I want to get a rolling average of the field "score" over all of the preceding days for each distinct "record_type" and "something_ind"

Data:

[image]

Desired Output:
[image]

SQL query:

```
select
     date
    ,record_type
    ,something_ind
    ,avg(score) over(partition by date, record_type, something_ind order by date, record_type, something_ind rows between 6 preceding and current row as rolling_average_score
from table
group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: By "rolling average" do you mean "accumulated average"?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get a rolling average of the field `score` over all of the preceding days for each distinct `record_type` and `something_ind`.

Use window functions. As I understood your question, you want:

```
select
    t.*,
    avg(score) over(
        partition by record_type, something_ind 
        order by date
    ) avg_score
from mytable t
```